# Data not moving view to controller, I have tried with all possible solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

When I Press Save button all fields {email,name..} gets null that's
          why code is not working.
 Just need to get data from html text boxes and use values in controller block.

View:---

```
 @model RenderCshtml.Models.ContactModel 
        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_TemplateView.cshtml";
        }
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ContactForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
        {
        <section id="MainContents" style="padding-top:50px">
            @*<script src="~Content/ContactUs/ContactValidation.js"></script>*@
            <script src="~Content/ContactUs/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
            <script src="~Content/ContactUs/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~Content/ContactUs/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div>
                        @if (ViewBag.Message == null)
                        {
                            <div>
                                <form method="post" id = "ContactForm">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label asp-for="Name">Name</label>
                                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control"/>
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Name"
                                              class="text-muted"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label asp-for="Email">Email</label>
                                        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Email"
                                              class="text-muted"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label asp-for="Subject">Subject</label>
                                        <input asp-for="Subject" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Subject"
                                              class="text-muted"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label asp-for="Message">Message</label>
                                        <textarea rows="5" cols="15"
                                                  asp-for="Message" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Message"
                                              class="text-muted"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <button type="submit"
                                                class="btn btn-success">
                                            Send
                                        </button>
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <div>
                            @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
                            {
                                <div>@ViewBag.Message</div>


                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
```

Controller:----

```
  public ActionResult Contact()
        {       
            return View(new ContactModel());
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Contact(ContactModel vm)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    MailMessage msz = new MailMessage();
                    msz.From = new MailAddress(vm.Email);//Email which you are getting 
                                                         //from contact us page 
                    msz.To.Add("dinesh.joshi1794@gmail.com");//Where mail will be sent 
                    msz.Subject = vm.Subject;
                    msz.Body = vm.Message;
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

                    smtp.Port = 587;

                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
                    ("securedj94@gmail.com", "!l0veum0m");

                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                    smtp.Send(msz);

                    ModelState.Clear();
                    ViewBag.Message = "Thank you for Contacting us ";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    ViewBag.Message = $" Sorry we are facing Problem here {ex.Message}";
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Model:------

```
 public class ContactModel
{


    public string Name { get; set; }    

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }       

}
```

Comment: is your ModelState.IsValid true?

Comment: have you tried to use textboxfor or textareafor ? since they link to the model and are posted directly

Comment: Roxy'Pro ModelState.IsValid  is true. I have tested with breakpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using asp.net mvc4 or higher this could work for you but you didn't specify which version you used so ill post it anyway in case it helps

instead of using input like this :

```
<input asp-for="Name" class="form-control"/>
```

you could use textboxfor since it will be linked to the model and posted to the controller

here is an exemple of a textboxfor for your name input and you can do the same for the others

```
@Html.TextBoxfor(m => n.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: I am using mvc 4